# fscanf is crashing program

Tags: c, sdl

i am working on a little project and i would like to know why this piece of code is causing my program to crash.

PLAYER_FILE_PATH -- "player.txt"

```
sprite=yoshi.bmp
width=64
height=64
frames=8
alignment=1
animate=1
```

program

```
      FILE *pfile = fopen(PLAYER_FILE_PATH, "r");
if (!pfile)
{
    debug_printf("could not open player file for reading!\n");
    return;
}
fscanf(pfile, "sprite=%s\n\
               width=%d\n\
               height=%d\n\
               frames=%d\n\
               alignment=%d\n\
               animate=%d",
               player_entity.entity_sprite.imgloc,
               &player_entity.entity_sprite.width,
               &player_entity.entity_sprite.height,
               &player_entity.entity_sprite.frames,
               &player_entity.entity_sprite.oscdir,
               &player_entity.entity_sprite.osc);
fclose(pfile);
```

Comment: could you show a "player_entity" definition?

Comment: Make sure that `player_entity.entity_sprite.imgloc` is properly allocated (either a buffer with lifetime tied to the lifetime of `player_entity` or dynamically allocated by calling `malloc`).

Comment: Pro tip: **[Select Isn't Broken](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)**. _You_ are crashing the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll need to see your definition of player_entity to know for sure. You probably have not properly defined "imgloc", which needs to point to some safely allocated piece of memory. For example, the following definition will core dump unless imgloc is properly initialized:

```
struct {
  struct {
    char *imgloc;
    int width;
    int height;
    int frames;
    int oscdir;
    int osc;
  } entity_sprite;
} player_entity;
```

This core dump will be avoided if you replace the imgloc line above with something like

```
char imgloc[100];
```

However, I'd be very careful using fscanf to read strings, since if the string is too long, it will overflow the given buffer. Perhaps try fgets instead just for the string part and fscanf for the rest.

Comment: i would use fgets but it reads the whole line and not just the portion i need it to

Comment: @OliverSikes How about limiting the number of characters `fscanf` will take for the string: `fscanf(pfile, "%99s", stuff.imgloc)`?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: It looks like fscanf with "%99s" will indeed work. Make sure the string buffer has an extra byte to hold the terminating NULL. (For example, "%99s" requires char buf[100].) I would then check to see whether there may have been a buffer overflow, for example `if (strlen(buf) == 99) ...`. If this condition is met, I'd abort the program with an error message rather than trying to recover, but that's up to the application. Trying to recover can get tricky.

Comment: Yes. I used 99 because you had `char imgloc[100];` in your answer :-) Which of abort, retry, ignore to choose depends, but for this one I also think aborting is the most likely candidate.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have not created a buffer to hold the value for imgloc, using malloc or the stack.

Comment: Thanks. I meant a pointer to a buffer on the stack in a function somewhere earlier in the call chain. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea - in general - is to use a memory debugger (such as valgrind) while you are developing your application.

That way you can make sure from the start that your program doesn't leak memory (a nightmare to debug later), and you can detect reading from or writing into memory that you don't have to access to (which causes a segfault, crashing your program).

In your particular case, Valgrind would have alerted you that you are writing to a memory address X that you don't have access to (and possibly using uninitialized memory), giving you the file name and the line number if you compiled with debugging information (-g). In that case, it would have pointed you to fscanf - so you would give it a closer look. If you can't find the problem by looking at the line, you'd split it up into reading the parameters one by one, until it (presumably) would point you to the line where you assign the string.

While that would not *solve* the problem if you didn't know that char* doesn't allocate any memory (beyond reserving the size of a pointer), it gives you a better idea where to start looking. Of course, now you know that you need to reserve memory, so you'd immediately apply that knowledge when you see the issue again.